# Flux of the intersection (sphere and plane)

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+z^2,2xy,y^2)$. Compute the curve integral $\int_C \ F \cdot \ dr$ where C is the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and the plane $y+z=1$ traversed clockwise from the origin.

My approach: I "Completed the square" and got $x^2+(y-\frac{1}{2})+(z-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$, but correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$. Where is my fault? I think the problem is the normal vector? No? Help me please.

[image]

Comment: You should type in your work instead of uploading an image. Images cannot be searched and the clarity depends on one's handwriting. It is not encouraged on the site.

Comment: The curl you found has a mistake in the z-component. Also given plane $y+z = 1$, you should take projection either in xy or yz plane by eliminating $z$ or $y$ from the combined equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface formed by the intersection of the given plane and the sphere is a disc that lies in the plane $y + z = 1$. The normal vector to the surface is $(0, 1, 1)$.

Please note that $ \displaystyle \nabla \times \vec F = (2y, 2z, 2y)$

So in the plane $y + z = 1,  \displaystyle (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \vec n = 2 (y + z) = 2$

Now we find the projection of the disc in the xy-plane.

$x^2 + y^2 + (1-y)^2 \leq 1 \implies \displaystyle x^2 + 2 \left(y- \frac12\right)^2 \leq \frac12$

$\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{1/2} + \frac{(y- 1/2)^2}{1/4} \leq 1$

The area of the ellipse $ \displaystyle \frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{a^2} = 1$ is given by $ \pi ab$. So in this case,  $A = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$. If you need to evaluate it using integral, I will leave it for you to choose the right change of variable and transform it into a unit circle.

So, $ \displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat n ~ dS$

$ \displaystyle = 2 \iint_D dA = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Okay thank you! But why do you use the normal vector and NOT the unit normal $n=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,1)$?

Comment: @MathLover you can do that but then note that $dS = |\vec n| \cdot dA$ so you eventually get $ \vec F \cdot \hat n ~ dS = \vec F \cdot \frac{\vec n}{|\vec n|} ~ |\vec n| dA$. $dA$ is the area element of the projection of surface element area $dS$ in xy-plane.

Comment: So instead of normalizing for dot product with the vector field and then multiplying by magnitude of the normal vector to map $dS$ to $dA$, we generally use the normal vector in the dot product itself and then integrate wrt $dA$. See for more details: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx and https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx

Comment: @MathLover is this clear?

Comment: I think yes, But i we parametrize the surface with $S(r,t)=(rcost, rsint, 1-rsint)$ then the normal becomes $(0,r,r)$ as i did, the wrong i did was the curl, okay. But is the rest of the solution correct? I integrate for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thank you so much. And how do i mention you btw? @Math_lover? :D

Comment: The parametrization is correct. The curl had a small mistake but the main issue is with the intersection surface equation you found and you are integrating with $0 \leq r \leq \frac1 {\sqrt2}$ but the projection of the surface in xy or xz plane is an ellipse and not a circle.

Comment: Now I understand you very clear! Thanks alot!